# What is a proper way to create a type for Vue props

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, typescript-typings, vue-props

I'm trying to create a custom `type` for my prop in Vue js, I've created a types folder and added it in the `tsconfig.typeRoots` the IntelliSense and all the other things work correctly, no issues at compile time but when I visit that component, I get an error that `Car is not defined` but I have already defined it and it works at other places but after checking official documentation I got to know that prop expects a `constructor` so I redefined the type to `declare class Car` and added a constructor prototype but again the same issue.

Here are the files:
**car component**

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";

export default Vue.extend({
  name: "the-car",
  props: {
    car: {
      required: true,
      type: Car,
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

**the `types/common/index.d.ts` declaration file**

```
declare class Car {
    name: String;
    image: String;
    kms: Number;
    gears: String;
    desc: String;
    fuel: String;
    engine: String;
    price: Number;
    constructor(name: String, image: String, kms: Number, gears: String, desc: String, fuel: String, engine: String, price: Number);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I think you need to import the `index.d.ts` file in the component.

Comment: @YashMaheshwari I've already added an entry in the `tsconfig.json` and type checking works well without importing

Answer (score 30, accepted):

type declaration such as `type: Car` or `type: Object as Car` will not work because in Vue, it provides additional functionality like prop validation which goes beyond the standard type checking that you get in Typescript.

While `type: Object as () => Car` will work, the proper way to handle this is by using Vue's helper method `PropType`.

```js
import { PropType } from 'vue'

props: {
  car: {
    type: Object as PropType<Car>,
    required: true,
  },
},
```

Check this [Typescript Support docs (v2)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Annotating-Props)([v3](https://vuejs.org/api/utility-types.html#proptype-t)) from Vue.js for more info about annotating props.